# jsTree : How to get IDs of selected nodes to root node in jsTree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jstree

How to get IDs of selected nodes to  root node in jsTree?

Assume C is selected node then How can I get All parent IDs of C.

A

- B

  - C

    +C1

    +c2

Following code will return only immediate parent ID:
If I selected **C** then I get only **B**

```
 .bind("select_node.jstree", function (event, data) {  
    //`data.rslt.obj` is the jquery extended node that was clicked          
    alert("Selected node = "+ data.rslt.obj.attr("id"));
    alert("Parent of Selected node = "+ data.inst._get_parent(data.rslt.obj).attr("id"))
 });
```

Output:

`Selected node = C`

`Parent of Selected node = B`

Is there any way to get all parent nodes ID i.e. Selected node to root node ?

- How to get all child nodes of selected node in jsTree ?

Any help or guidance in this matter would be appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `parents` in jQuery to get all parents, filtering out by `li` because all tree items are `li` in `jstree`, try this:

```
var parents = data.rslt.obj.parents("li");
```

And for children use `children` in jQuery, like so:

```
var children = data.rslt.obj.parent().find('li');
```

**EDIT Using the above, here's how to get all parent and children and put them in all an array for each:**

**Parents:**

```
var parents = [];
data.rslt.obj.parents("li").each(function () {
    parents.push({ id: $(this).attr("id"), description: $(this).children("a").text() });
});
```

**Children:**

```
var children = [];
data.rslt.obj.find("li").each(function () {
    children.push({ id: $(this).attr("id"), description: $(this).children("a").text() });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply mattytommo . list of parents returns [object HTMLLIElement]. How to get ID and text of that "object HTMLLIElement" ?

Comment: Do you want all of the IDs of the parents or just the immediate parent? Let me know and I'll change my code :)

Comment: mattytommo :) If "C" is selected by user then I should get all IDs and node value(text) of all parent i.e(B,A). I am implementing dual tree in jstree. In that if user selected node(leaf/non-leaf) from left tree then I want to copy hierarchy of selected node to root node in left tree on particular event.

Comment: var children = data.rslt.obj.children("li") Not returning child's of selected node. children.lenght=0 always plz chk

Comment: Check my edit, gets all of your children and puts them in an array by id and text, same for parents too.

Comment: Perfect for Parents :) mattytommo. But In case of children if I selected any node then I am getting child nodes + siblings of selected node :( . I want only child nodes of selected node. How to ?

Comment: Doh. Check my new edit on children, the children selector is `data.rslt.obj.find("li")`

Comment: Thanks :) . How to get all leaf nodes(id & text) present in jstree ? and How to get all nodes(root/node/leaf-node) from jstree ?

Comment: Hmmm now that would be a different solution entirely. If you ask another question I'll have a go at it for you :)

Comment: :)  See different question for you :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10293869/jstree-how-to-get-all-leaf-nodes-from-jstree  and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296410/jstree-how-to-get-all-nodes-from-jstree and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223212/dual-jstree-implementation I hope, I will get all answer from you. As you have good hands on JsTree Implementation :) Waiting for your positive reply

Comment: I asked different question for you. [#1] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223212/dual-jstree-implementation  [#2] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10293869/jstree-how-to-get-all-leaf-nodes-from-jstree  [#3] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296410/jstree-how-to-get-all-nodes-from-jstree :)

Comment: I keep having `data.rslt` as `undefined`. What could be causing this?

Comment: @mmcrae Sounds like your tree isn't binding properly. Is your selector for your tree correct, no JS errors or anything?

Answer (score 12):

**1 More easy solution**

```
 .get_path ( node , id_mode )
```

return the path to a node, either as an array of IDs or as an array of node names.
mixed node : This can be a DOM node, jQuery node or selector pointing to an element within the tree, whose path we want.bool id_mode : If set to true IDs are returned instead of the names of the parents. Default is false.

```
// To get path [ID or Name] from root node to selected node 

var ids = data.inst.get_path('#' + data.rslt.obj.attr('id'),true);

// Returns IDs from root to selected node

var names = data.inst.get_path('#' + data.rslt.obj.attr('id'),false); 

// Returns Name's from root to selected node 

alert("Path [ID or Name] from root node to selected node = ID's = "+ids+" :: Name's = "+names);
```

Comment: Excellent. Just what I needed.  I wanted the text of the root node for any selected node, so I just used `data.inst.get_path(data.rslt.obj)[0]`

Comment: use `data.instance` instead of `data.inst` to get it working with jsTree 3. Thank's for the help!