# Dual jsTree Implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, tree, javascript-framework, jstree

I am newbie to jsTree, I want to use dual jsTree.

**[left JsTrree]     [ >> ]      [right JsTrree]**

">>" : Button for copy selected node from left to right jsTree

I want to copy partial tree hierarchy from left to right jsTree.

- No duplication of node.
- I don't want to copy child node of selected node
- Only selected node from left jsTree merge into right jsTree as per right jsTree structure

If user selected any node from left jsTree then on button(">>") click I want to copy partial tree from selected node to root node.

**Left jsTree as follows** "

```
 Root
     -----A
          -----A1
               -----A1.1
               -----A1.2
          -----A2
               -----`A2.1`
               -----A2.2

     -----B
          -----B1
          -----B2

     -----C
          -----C1
               -----C1.1
               -----C2.2
```

**--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**
Now assume user selected node A2.1 then after button(">>") click  following partial tree should display in right jsTree

**[#1] Right jsTree:**

```
 Root
     -----A
          -----A2
               -----`A2.1`
```

Now Root node is added in right jsTree now on wards only selected node should merge into right jsTree.

**--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

Now assume user selected  C1 then Only C1 should merge into right jsTree.

**[#2] Right jsTree structure after C1 added from left jsTree:**

```
Root
     -----A
          -----A2
               -----A2.1 
     -----C
          -----`C1`
```

Assume user selected  A1 then A1 should merge into appropriate place
**[#3] Right jsTree structure after A1 added from left jsTree:**

```
Root
     -----A
          -----`A1`
          -----A2
               -----A2.1                   
     -----C
          -----C1
```

My workaround till now is as follows

after selection of node from left jsTree I am building xml from selected node to root node.
and generated partial_xml_string stored into cookie. OnClick of (">>")button I am reading value of partial_xml_string from cookie + clearing cookie value of partial_xml_string.
[#1] case done properly. Is there any other good way to achive [#1] case ?

Using .get_path ( node , id_mode ) I am getting path(ID & Name) from root to leaf node

if id_mode =true then node **IDs** = **Root.id,A.id, A2.id, A2.1.id**

if id_mode =false then node **Name's** = **Root, A, A2, A2.1**

**Is it possible to set this path to right side of jsTree ?**

**If yes then How to set this path ?** 
**If path already exist then how to prevent copying** ? else merge selected node to right jsTree.

**--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

Using .bind("select_node.jstree", function (event, data) we can handle event on selected node. How to handle event onClick of **+** **icon** ?

Consider my left jsTree contains only one Root node with + icon then How to handle onClick event on + icon? **see ink's answer**

**I want to get child nodes of selected node how to append that list of child nodes to selected node ?**

How to achieve [#2] and [#3] using jsTree functions ?

Any help or guidance in this matter would be appreciated.

Comment: I Solve this Question, will updated answer here :)

Answer (score 1):

I can help you with [+] click event.
You have to modify your jquery.jstree.js (uncompressed version).
Open it, find string with `toggle_node  : function (obj)` (there is a tab symbol so search `toggle_node`) and add 1 line here. After edit it must be:

```
        toggle_node : function (obj) {
            obj = this._get_node(obj);
            this.__callback(obj); // these line must be added
            if(obj.hasClass("jstree-closed")) { return this.open_node(obj); }
            if(obj.hasClass("jstree-open")) { return this.close_node(obj);}             
        },
```

Now you can bind a callback as usual for `toggle_node` event. Here is example:

```
    $("#your_jstree").bind("toggle_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
        is_opened = $(data.rslt).hasClass('jstree-open') ? false : true;
        node_id = $(data.rslt).attr('id');
        alert('node with id='+node_id+' is '+(is_opened ? 'opening' : 'closing')+' now.');          
    })
```

These callback calls *before* node opens or closes. And also this event does not fire while the tree is loading, like if you use `open_node` event.

Comment: Thanks for reply. [+] click event working fine as per your answer