# jsTree : How to get all leaf nodes from jstree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors, jstree

I want to get all leaf-nodes(ID & text of node) from jsTree ?

I am not using checkbox ui : jsTree.

```
   Root
      -----A
           -----A1
                  -----A1.1

           -----A2
                  -----A2.1

      -----B

           -----B2

       -----C
            -----C1
                  -----C1.1
```

I want list of leaf nodes from jsTree.

**Expected Output : [A1.1, A2.1, B2, C1.1 ]**

Any help or guidance in this matter would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$('.jstree-leaf').each(function(){
  var id   = $(this).attr('id');
  var text = $(this).children('a').text();
});
```

Comment: I agree with the solution. This can be called from any function. I would change two things. 1) What is the need for substr(5) on the ID. 2) The text should be trimmed. $('.jstree-leaf').each(function(){
  var id   = $(this).attr('id');
  var text = $(this).children('a').text().trim();
});

Comment: @MMeah Thanks for reply. I also agree with solution. this iteration will return all leaf node present in jsTree. I am facing 1 problem. My page contains 2 jsTree. tree1 and tree2. I want only tree2's all leaf node. How I can achieve this ?

Comment: @Iddo My page contains 2 jsTree. tree1 and tree2. I want only tree2's all leaf node. How I can achieve this ?

Comment: @VaibhaV to talk to individual trees, they must be distinguishable. Give them id="tree1" and and id="tree2", then create a selector for them. $('#tree2 .jstree-leaf').each...

Comment: @MMeah Can you help me on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223212/dual-jstree-implementation

Comment: It gave me only root leaf nodes, not all leaf nodes of tree.

Answer (score -1):

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// @name        :
// @description :   function
// @params      :
// @return      :
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function jstreeIterateNodes(
    treeOwner ,
    node , 
    fnCallbackCondition ,
    bRecursive ,
    arrCollector
){

    var 
        childNodes = node.children ,
        arrCollector = ( arrCollector ) ? arrCollector : [] ,
        bUseCallback = ( typeof fnCallbackCondition === "function" ) ? true : false ,
        nodeItreator = null;

    for(
        var i = 0;
        i < childNodes.length;
        ++i
    ){

        nodeItreator = treeOwner.get_node( childNodes[i] );

        if( bUseCallback ){

            if( fnCallbackCondition( nodeItreator , node ) ){

                arrCollector.push({
                    node : nodeItreator,
                    parent : node
                });

            }

        }
        if( bRecursive ){
            jstreeIterateNodes(
                treeOwner ,
                nodeItreator ,
                fnCallbackCondition ,
                arrCollector
            ); 
        }
    }

    return arrCollector;
}
var 
    _your_jstree_ = $("#YOUR_TREE_ELEMENT").jstree( true ) ,
    bRecursiveItreation = false , // could be true for recursive
    arrCollected = null;

arrCollected = jstreeIterateNodes( 
    _your_jstree_ , 
    _your_jstree_.get_node( "some_node_id" ) , 
    function _your_filter_callback_( itrated_node , parent_itrated_node ){
      // Do what ever and return true to collect
    } ,
    bRecursiveItreation 
);

// DO SOMTHING WITH arrCollected which contains all collected nodes
```

Comment: Could you add a paragraph explaining your code, please?