# How to get parent node properties to child node in JSTree Using RShiny Application

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, jstree, jstreer

I am working with JSTree using R-shiny. I am trying to generate a child node which will get its parents' node properties. I have tried many times but could not get the desired output. I am using the following code. please take a look and tell update the code. Thanks

```
library(jsTreeR)
library(shiny)

nodes <- list(
  list(
    text = "Menu",
    state = list(opened = TRUE),
    children = list(
      list(
        text = "Dog",
        type = "moveable",
        children = list(list(text = "Dog"))
      ),
      list(
        text = "Cat",
        type = "moveable",
        children = list(list(text = "Cat"))
      ),
      list( 
        text = "Rat",
        type = "moveable",
        children = list(list(text = "Rat"))
      )
    )
  ),
  list(
    text = ">>> Drag here <<<",
    type = "target",
    state = list(opened = TRUE)
  )
)

checkCallback <- JS(
  "function(operation, node, parent, position, more) { ",
  "  if(operation === 'copy_node') {",
  "    var n = parent.children.length;",
  "    if(position !== n || parent.id === '#' || node.parent !== 'j1_1' || parent.type !== 'target') {",
  "      return false;", # prevent moving an item above or below the root
  "    }",               # and moving inside an item except a 'target' item
  "  }",
  "  if(operation === 'delete_node') {",
  "    Shiny.setInputValue('deletion', position + 1);",
  "  }",
  "  return true;",      # allow everything else
  "}"
)

customMenu <- JS(
  "function customMenu(node) {",
  "  var tree = $('#mytree').jstree(true);", 
  "  var items = {",
  "    'delete' : {",
  "      'label'  : 'Delete',",
  "      'action' : function (obj) { tree.delete_node(node); },",
  "      'icon'   : 'glyphicon glyphicon-trash'",
  "     }",
  "  }",
  "  return items;",
  "}")

dnd <- list(
  always_copy = TRUE,
  inside_pos = "last", 
  is_draggable = JS(
    "function(node) {",
    "  return node[0].type === 'moveable';",
    "}"
  )
)

mytree <- jstree(
  nodes, dragAndDrop = TRUE, dnd = dnd, checkCallback = checkCallback,
  contextMenu = list(items = customMenu),
  types = list(moveable = list(), target = list())
)

script <- '
$(document).ready(function(){
  var LETTERS = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"];
  var Visited = {};
  $("#mytree").on("copy_node.jstree", function(e, data){
    var oldid = data.original.id;
    var visited = Object.keys(Visited);
    if(visited.indexOf(oldid) === -1){
      Visited[oldid] = 0;
    }else{
      Visited[oldid]++;
    }
    var letter = LETTERS[Visited[oldid]];
    var node = data.node;
    var id = node.id;
    var index = $("#"+id).index() + 1;
    var text = index + ". " + node.text + " " + letter; 
    Shiny.setInputValue("choice", text);
    var instance = data.new_instance;
    instance.rename_node(node, text);
  });
});
'
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  tags$div(class = "header", checked = NA,tags$p(tags$script(HTML(script)))),
  
  # In lieu of the above tags$div, the below tags$head does the same for the senior child:
  # tags$head(tags$script(HTML(script))),
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 4,jstreeOutput("mytree")),
    column(width = 8,verbatimTextOutput("choices"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output[["mytree"]] <- renderJstree(mytree)
  Choices <- reactiveVal(data.frame(choice = character(0)))
  observeEvent(input[["choice"]],{Choices(rbind(Choices(),data.frame(choice = input[["choice"]])))})
  observeEvent(input[["deletion"]], {Choices(Choices()[-input[["deletion"]], , drop = FALSE])})
  output[["choices"]] <- renderPrint({Choices()})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This will look like this .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxJEH.png)

But I want it to be look like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHllo.png)

Comment: So you want to drag "Dog" to "1. Dog A" with a copy of "1. Dog A"? That's strange. And if by accident your drag "Cat" to "1. Dog A" ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Did you test the code? Once you will drag the cat it will only generate the cat child not dog child. So my idea is if the parent is 1.Cat-A and Child is "Cat" so the child should be "1. Cat-A" instead of Cat. Is that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with an action in the context menu?

```
customMenu <- JS(
  "function customMenu(node) {",
  "  var tree = $('#mytree').jstree(true);", # 'mytree' is the Shiny id or the elementId
  "  var items = {",
  "    'delete' : {",
  "      'label'  : 'Delete',",
  "      'action' : function (obj) { tree.delete_node(node); },",
  "      'icon'   : 'glyphicon glyphicon-trash'",
  "     },",
  "    'copy_to_child' : {",
  "      'label'  : 'Copy to child',",
  "      'action' : function (obj) { tree.create_node(node, { text: node.text }, 'last'); tree.open_node(node); },",
  "      'icon'   : 'glyphicon glyphicon-duplicate'",
  "     }",
  "  }",
  "  return items;",
  "}")
```

Comment: Laurent thanks let me try this.

Comment: it is working in context menu fine Is there any way, which I want it to be done?

Comment: Laurent I want to like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10293869/jstree-how-to-get-all-leaf-nodes-from-jstree

Comment: Sorry? What do you mean? I don't undertand your question and your "wish". Open a new question and elaborate if you have another request. And my first name is Stéphane ;-)