# jstree get checked and unchecked nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, jstree

I want to get checked nodes and unchecked nodes in 2 separate arrays from my jstree.

I have seen `.get_checked` and `.get_unchecked` function but they return me all the nodes that are presently checked and unchecked. (i.e. If a node is unchecked and I have not unchecked it then I still get it using `.get_unchecked`. I want to prevent this from happening). I am ready to do major changes in the api also. Any directions?

Can I get the change event for checkbox. I have also tried `change_state` but that works for only one node that is clicked.

Comment: can you provide any code ?, make jsfiddle pls

Answer (score 2):

As i understand it is almost impossible without rewriting checkbox plugin of jstree) to handle single  event of checked box, as they just on each check/uncheck event redraw all parents and childs of the clicked folder.

Here the simple [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HFtjE/):

all work for me,

HTML

```
<div id="demo1" class="demo">
    <ul>
        <li id="phtml_1">
            <a href="#">Root node 1</a>
            <ul>
                <li id="phtml_2" class="jstree-checked">
                    <a href="#">Child node 1</a>
                </li>
                <li id="phtml_3">
                    <a href="#">A Child node 2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="phtml_4">
            <a href="#">Root node 2</a>
             <ul>
                <li id="phtml_2" >
                    <a href="#">Child node 1</a>
                </li>
                <li id="phtml_3">
                    <a href="#">A Child node 2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>​
```

JS

```
$(function() {
    var tree = $("#demo1").jstree({
        "plugins": ["themes", "html_data", "checkbox", "sort", "ui"]
    });
    tree.bind("open_node.jstree close_node.jstree check_node.jstree uncheck_node.jstree", function(e) {
        console.log("Event", e);
        console.log('Cheked:', tree.jstree('get_checked'));
        console.log('Uncheked:', tree.jstree('get_unchecked'));
    });
});​
```

Comment: in console: _GET http://static.jstree.com/v.1.0pre/jquery.jstree.js 404 (Not Found)_

Comment: @DanStopka http://jsfiddle.net/HFtjE/29/

the get_unchecked is removed from latest version, you can use `$.not()` to filter out checked nodes, also something with `check_node` event happen, so I used `click` event

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers on this or other posts worked for me, but found a way of scanning the nodes and maintaining an array of unchecked items.

My approach was to first get a list of all the nodes iteratively and I referred to code from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56618663/820754) to get a list of nodes (with my own tweak to recursively iterate through the entire tree, since the OP did not go into nested levels, plus I only wanted the ids).

Then I got a li tags with a filter function for all clicked and undetermined items and a for loop on this, within which I removed these from the master list I retrieved previously.

```
$("#getUnchecked").bind("click", function () {

  //get a list of all nodes in the entire tree recursively - function in fiddle.
  ids = get_jstree_order('#tree > ul');

  var selNodes = $('li').filter(function () {
      //Find nodes that have jstree-clicked - or clicked items and
      //Find nodes that are undetermined
      return $(this).children('a.jstree-clicked').length
          || $(this).children('a').children('i.jstree-undetermined').length;
  });
  selNodes.each(function () {
      //find the position of the checked or undetermined id 
      let pos = ids.indexOf(this.id);
      //remove it from the master list, as we are filtering it down to just the unchecked ones
      ids.splice(pos, 1);
  })

  console.log(ids);
});
```

For a working example, check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Azerax/f46j7gmd/70/) here.