# How to get all nodes level of JStree

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I am trying to get all the nodes with their levels, I mean that when the tree is completely loaded I want to get the node's levels of all of them.

I tried to do this:

```
var idList = [];
var jsonNodes = $('#albero').jstree(true).get_json('#', { flat: true });
$.each(jsonNodes, function (i, val) {
    idList.push($(val).attr('id'));
});
```

But it gives me the level of the selected node, not all of them.
My Tree looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jsTree : How to get all nodes from jstree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296410/jstree-how-to-get-all-nodes-from-jstree)

Comment: I checked that question and the answers but it does not work in my case. I mean it selects the nodes but only if I select them one by one, not after the tree is loaded.