# How to get title of immediate parent of a child node in jsTree?

Tags: jstree

How to get the title of immediate parent of child node in jsTree.
I have tried the following code, but its giving me the html li element and I want the title of parent element.

var parent = data.inst._get_parent(data.rslt.obj);

Please help

Comment: How do you call above piece of code? Could you provide jsfiddle?

Comment: Hi Radek,
I have written the given code in bind function of jsTree. Here is the code-
    .bind("select_node.jstree", function(e,data){
        var parent = data.inst._get_parent(data.rslt.obj);
        //var parent = data.rslt.obj.parents("li");
    })

Answer (score 0):

Use parents in jQuery to get all parents, filtering out by li because all tree items are li in jstree, try this:

```
var parents = data.rslt.obj.parents("li");
And for children use children in jQuery, like so:

var children = data.rslt.obj.parent().find('li');
```

[jsTree : How to get IDs of selected nodes to root node in jsTree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10140057/jstree-how-to-get-ids-of-selected-nodes-to-root-node-in-jstree)

Comment: Thanks for your reply brightboy! I tried this too but how do I get the title/text of the parent node?

Comment: please alert data.rslt.obj to check the properties of this object.

Comment: I checked the properties and found one property named "text", but it gives the text of each and every node starting from root node. I only want the text of immediate parent. Please help on this.

Comment: Any help on this. I need this urgently.

Answer (score 0):

```
.bind("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
  var parent=data.inst._get_parent(data.rslt.obj);
  alert(parent.find('a').first().text()); 
});
```

Note that you have to use `ui` plugin to use ._get_parent function

Working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/radek/C67s3/5/)

Comment: Thanks for reply Radek. But I am getting following error - 
"TypeError: parent.find is not a function" while using "parent.find('a').first().text()". Please help.

Comment: As you can see in my jsfiddle it works. So you need to double check your code, syntax, all necessary plugins are defined, version of jstree, jquery etc...