# How to get full path of selected node in jstree?(root node to selected node)

Tags: jquery, jstree

I want to build a directory management system where user can create,rename,delete directories and save files in directories. for this i am using jquery jstree.

```
my jsTree is like:-

*A(root node)
  *b
  *C
    *D
```

and i want to get the full path of selected node on button click. if user select the `*D` folder then path should be `"A/C/d"`,if user select C then path should be `"A/C"`.
any help suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of [jsTree : How to get IDs of selected nodes to root node in jsTree?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10140057/jstree-how-to-get-ids-of-selected-nodes-to-root-node-in-jstree)

Comment: I have seen this this question but i don't know what is bind() event. I need to get the full path on button click. I tied to use var ids = data.inst.get_path('#' + data.rslt.obj.attr('id'),true); but don't know what is 'data' there.

Comment: bind is not about jsTree, it's jQuery. If you want more help, please add a working demo of your jsTree

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have used this:

```
.on('changed.jstree', function (e, data) {
  var path = data.instance.get_path(data.node,'/');
  console.log('Selected: ' + path); 
})
```

Answer (score 5):

you can found it simply by

`$('#drives_tree').jstree().get_path($('#drives_tree').jstree("get_selected", true)[0], ' > ')`

here drives_tree is id of the jstree in my case