# How to get all the children nodes from the selected node in jstree

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

`var selectedNode = $("#evts").jstree("get_selected");`

Hi everyone.. I am using the above code to get the selected node from the tree. **How to get all the children nodes for the selectedNode**...I am using jstree 3.3...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10140057/jstree-how-to-get-ids-of-selected-nodes-to-root-node-in-jstree

Answer (score 5):

```
var currentNode = $("#evts").jstree("get_selected");
   var childrens = $("#evts").jstree("get_children_dom",currentNode);

   for(var i=0;i<childrens.length;i++)
   {
   alert(childrens[i].innerText);
   }
```

the above code works as expected...

Answer (score 3):

```
 var selectedNode = $("#evts").jstree("get_selected");
 var node_info=$('#evts').jstree("get_node",selectedNode[0]);

 // this node_info contains **children_d** an array of all child nodes' id .
 // **parents** an array of parent nodes


    alert(node_info.children_d.join(','));
    alert(node_info.parents.join(','));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
   // Return childen even if not rendered
  function getAllChildrenNodes(parentNode, children=[]) {
    var node = $("#SimpleJSTree").jstree("get_node",parentNode);
    children.push(node.id);
    if (node.children) {
      for (var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
        getAllChildrenNodes(node.children[i], children);
      }
    }
    return children;
  }
 var selectingInProccess=0;
  // select all child nodes when parent selected
  $('#SimpleJSTree').on('select_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
    if(selectingInProccess==0){
      selectingInProccess=1;
      var closedNodes=[];
      var children = getAllChildrenNodes(data.node.id);
      children.forEach(function(node){
        var nodeClosed = ($("#SimpleJSTree").jstree("is_closed",node));
        $("#SimpleJSTree").jstree("select_node",node);
        if(nodeClosed){
          closedNodes.push(node);
        }
      });
      closedNodes.forEach(function(node){
        $("#SimpleJSTree").jstree("close_node",node,false);
      });
      selectingInProccess=0;
    }
  });

  // deselect all child nodes when parent deselected
  $('#SimpleJSTree').on('deselect_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
    if(selectingInProccess==0){
      selectingInProccess=1;
      var children = getAllChildrenNodes(data.node.id);
      children.forEach(function(node){
        $("#SimpleJSTree").jstree("deselect_node",node);
      });
      selectingInProccess=0;
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
enter $('button').on('click', function () {
var instance = $('#tree').jstree(true);
    selected = instance.get_selected()[0];
console.log(instance.get_node(selected).children);
});
```

If you want to do that in an event handler - it is even easier:

```
$('#tree').on('changed.jstree', function (e, data) {
console.log(data.instance.get_node(data.selected[0]).children);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `get_children_dom (obj)` for get childrens try...

```
var selectedNode = $("#evts").jstree("get_selected");
var childrens = get_children_dom(selectedNode);
```

Doc: https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=get_children_dom(obj)

Comment: No problem! if my answer has helped you accept and close the question!

Comment: ReferenceError: get_children_dom is not defined